# Sending password through sms in 'forgot password' - vulnerable to security?

Tags: android, security, sms

I am making an app in which we have to send password from server database via sms if user has forgotten his password. But, some of my colleagues told me that it could be vulnerable to security. Is is true?

I have searched for it on internet and found many articles saying that sms can be intercepted easily. So my question is very simple: Whether it is inappropriate to send forgot password via sms in client server Android app?

Comment: Its true, but how will some one know that the password belongs to which application if the sms is coming from server, or else you can create a random password which can be used to reset the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its true, but how will some one know that the password belongs to which application if the sms is coming from server, or else you can create a random password which can be used to reset the password. Keep some timeout for this random password, Like you have an OTP sms when you are doing online banking transactions. I suggest you NOT to send the actual password via sms, even Google uses the same mechanism to reset the password, [Take a Look at this Link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/152124?hl=en).